# Can be iteratedly integrate w.r.t. all direction $\Rightarrow$ integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ be bounded. Suppose $\int_0^1(\int_0^1 f(x,y)dy)dx$ and $\int_0^1(\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx)dy$ are all exist and equal. Then is $f$ Riemann integrable on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$? I tried to use Fubini's theorem, but the condition of that theroem doesn't suit in this case. Can I avoid digging into $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs?

Comment: Lebesgue integral or?

Comment: @user284331 Riemann.

Comment: Do you have an example where the iterated integrals exist but are **not** equal?

Comment: What is your definition for Riemann integrability on a square? (using rectangle grids?)

Comment: @H.H.Rugh: I presume so, namely induced by two partitions of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @user21820 Is it a hint? :)

Comment: @Eric: No I don't have a clue. My intuition tells me that if it is false, then such an example as I asked for may lead to a counter-example to your question. My intuition also tells me that it is true, and that it suffices for the iterated integrals to merely exist, so I do not know what to believe at the moment.

Comment: See if you can find a countable set, dense in the square, but such that each horizontal or vertical line meets the set in at most one point.  Then the two iterated integrals would be zero, but the whole thing is not 2-dmensional Riemann integrable.

Comment: @GEdgar : Was just writing the answer and then saw your comments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be no, but it depends possibly upon how you define
the objects in question.

I presume here that definitions are as follows:

For every $x\in [0,1]$: $F_x = \int_0^1 f(x,y)dy$ is defined as a Riemann integral, i.e. that the upper and lower integrals (w.r.t. step-functions on finite partitions into intervals) are equal and similarly for $F_y=\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx$.

For the double integral upper and lower integrals w.r.t finite partitions into rectangles should be equal.

In that case, let  $\Omega\subset [0,1]\times[0,1]$ be a countable dense subset of points $(x_n,y_n)$ with the property that for every $x\in [0,1]$, $y\in [0,1]$,
the sets $\{n: x_n=x\}$ and $\{n: y_n=y\}$ have cardinality 0 or 1.

Let $f$ be the indicator function on $\Omega$. Then you check that $F_x=F_y=0$ for every $x,y$ (since e.g. $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is zero everywhere except for at most one point) but that $f$ is not Riemann integrable. The upper integral equals one (you can not avoid the dense set) and the lower is zero.

Comment: I think Sierpinski has an example for the Lebesgue integral:  a non-measurable set in the square, so that each horizonal and vertical line meets it in finitely (or was it countably?) many points.

Comment: @GEdgar : Sounds nice. Found it in Rudin. Seems that in his example you get countable intersections with grid lines (and the conclusion being that the iterated integrals are not equal).

Comment: Oh so simple! But how do you get iterated Riemann integrals to exist but not equal?

Comment: You may take a subset (no longer countable) so that for every y, the set $\{x: (x,y)\in \Omega \}$ is  dense in $[0,1]$ but such that for each $x$, the set $\{y : (x,y)\in \Omega\}$ is a subset of an interval of length $0<\delta<1$. Then one iterated integral is bounded by $\delta$ the other is 1.

Comment: Btw, I just found that Wade's Introduction to Analysis also have such counterexample.